# SelectedIndexChanged DataBind error when using header filter

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, dropdown

I'm trying to filter my GridView with values from a header dropdown. 
However I get this error message: "**DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name '[*AnotherColumnThatIsNotSTATUS*]'**"

[AnotherColumnThatIsNotSTATUS] = another column for some reason and not **STATUS**?

Can anyone see what I´m missing?

```
protected void ddlStatusHeader_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
      DropDownList ddlStatusHeader = ((DropDownList)sender);


        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Status] FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tblStatus] WHERE [Status] LIKE '%' + @Status  + '%' ", con);            
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", ddlStatusHeader.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Status");
            gwActivity.DataSource = ds;
            gwActivity.DataBind();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I suspected your query just return one column instead of full column list with `SELECT [Status] FROM [tblStatus] WHERE ...`. Try using `SELECT *` instead and see if GridView rebinding from query properly.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue! THANK YOU!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me.Hope this helps..

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Select [text] from main where status='"+DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString()+"'";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Status");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified Columns for your Gridview??

Comment: I needed to specify all my columns and then i could rebind :)